# How to get a POST variable from asp.net web api?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

In c# asp.net 4.5.2, how do I get a post variable. I have this so far

```
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostMessage(HttpRequestMessage request, string pCompanyName, string pMessage, string language)
    {
    }
```

But these are all URL parameters. I want to move `string pMessage` into a POST body. From the client side I can send this by the `data` in jquery ajax.

```
data : {
    message : "test"
}
```

but how do I get this value from the c# side?

Thanks

Comment: `[FromBody]` attribute is a good place to start: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: Use a model in the front-end/JS side and have a similar model in your server side, then use the model as a parameter in the action like `PostMessage(YourModel messagerequestModel){ // your code }`.

Comment: What does your data look like in Dev Tools of the browser when you submit a request? Try matching the structure of the body (hierarchy, naming, etc.)

Comment: you have "message" in your ajax data but "pMessage" in your PostMessage method...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `[FromBody]` [attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api#using-frombody)

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostMessage(HttpRequestMessage request, string pCompanyName, string language, [FromBody] string pMessage)
{
}
```

But you actually need something like

```
 [HttpPost]
 public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostMessage([FromUri] string pCompanyName, [FromUri] string language, [FromBody] string pMessage)
 {
 }
```

Comment: I put `, [FromBody] string message` but it ends up null.

Comment: Did you try to also put `FromUri`? And show us please how do you make a request

Comment: @omega create one class `public class Test {
    public string message {get;set;}
}` and in for `[FromBody] Test test`

Answer (score 0):

Create a ViewModel as the following

```
class InputMessage
{
    public string pMessage { get; set; }
}
```

And then use this class as the parameter of your method:

```
 public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostMessage(HttpRequestMessage request, string pCompanyName, InputMessage message, string language)
    {
      // message.pMessage
    }
```